# Realloc() inside a function

Tags: c, pointers

im trying to make my own version of strcat() mixed with realloc. So the idea is, pass a char* declared on main and add memory dynamically.

the problem is i get **segmentation fault** every time i mean i tried all i know.

here is my code, i hope someone could help me:

main:

```
char* nombreCopia = "";
StrcatDynamic(&nombreCopia, argv[1]);
free(nombreCopia);
```

strcatDynamic:

```
    int StrcatDynamic(char** dest, const char* src)
   {
      char* aux;
      printf("%p\n", *dest);
      aux = realloc (*dest, (strlen(src) + strlen(*dest) + 1) );
      

      if (aux == NULL)
      {
         perror("ERROR\n");
      }
      else
      {
         *dest = aux;
      }
      strcat(*dest, src);


      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Code is calling `realloc()` with a pointer that was never allocated earlier.  `char* nombreCopia = "";` does not assign `nombreCopia` to allocated data.

Comment: BTW, `strcpy(*dest, src);` does not concatenate.

Comment: so, do you know what is the best way to fix it? load it with something?

Comment: thx i forgot to change that

Comment: If you change the call site init to `char* nombreCopia = NULL;`, it ought to work. You can't realloc a literal string.  Passing null causes it to behave as `malloc()`.

Comment: @Gene Not quite. `strlen(*dest)` would need to be adjusted. See my Answer.

Comment: Ah yes, true... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't `free` or `realloc` the string produced by `""`.

Simple solution:

```c
char* nombreCopia = strdup("");     // In lieu of `char* nombreCopia = "";`
```

What I would do:

```c
char* nombreCopia = NULL;           // In lieu of `char* nombreCopia = "";`
```

```c
( *dest ? strlen(*dest) : 0 )       // In lieu of `strlen(*dest)`
```